# Mobile App session handling with Spring

Tags: spring, mobile

I have to build an app for a school project with a front in React Native (mobile app Android and iOS) and back Java/Spring. The app is almost complete in design and request/response but there is no security ! Well, only password encryption... So I need to add some security to it.

The problem is, for now, when an user logged, I return his ID on success where it is stored in the mobile app storage. And on every request on server by GET/POST, even if the user isn't logged, the server send him the response. How can I resolve this the simpliest way ? There is session with spring-security, but I read that since mobile doesn't act like browser, it doesn't store cookies. I though of generating a token (but I don't know how to do it) and give in @Response. Everytime the user want to access ressources (i.e. travelling in the app), it send the token. But I think this is a bit complicated. The app is stateless, only login and and register can be accessible by everyone, all others views should need you to be logged.

Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement, I will suggest you the same thing what i did in my react-native app for maintaining session and my backend was nodejs where i used JWT for maintaining session in backend.

In my app i can only access two views without accesstoken i.e Login view and register so, Whenever you post a request with credentials from login screen then use react-native store(3rd party lib) to store accesstoken, email etc in your local. After login you have accesstoken saved you can use it anywhere.

Once you close the app and reenter the app then apply a check that if your store's accesstoken key is not null then then directly open the homepage which comes after login so in this way user don't have to login everytime whenever app reopens.

If the user clicks logout button then redirect him to login and delete accesstoken from the store.

Cheers:)

Comment: Thanks for this approach ! But I forget to mention that I am working in back.   But how I use JWT to maintainning access ? Because the problem is, for example everyone can do a GET with the link http://mylink.com/user?id=1 (that return the user profile with ID 1) while it should be possible only if the user is logged !

Comment: That is accesstoken is used so that no one without login access profile. You need to have authorization key, accesstoken and params

Comment: In nodejs JWT randomly generate an accesstoken which is different everytime.

Comment: That say, this accesstoken need to be provided in each request that need it, right ? Thus, I'm not sure that I understand the difference between authorization key and accesstoken. Authorization key is like permission of this user on the ressource. And accesstoken act as session ticket ?

Comment: Authorization key is application permission and accesstoken is user permission.

Comment: I did focused my research on JWT, and that pretty easy to implement and to understand. Thanks. But how do you prevent reject with JWT ? If an MITM succed to sniff the packet, he can use the token to authenticate.

Comment: I did not have a thought on that but I think authorization key plays the role of the private key.

Comment: Also, I saw on auth0 tutorial for JWT that we send token hover the http header. Is that an issue if I return the token in a Json format ?

Comment: auth0 in case of web and JWT is used in case of mobile app